# LeetCode TwoSum solution not working

Tags: c++, arrays, search, initialization, binary-search

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<iostream.h>
int bins(int* p,int lo,int hi,int t)
{//BinarySearch
    int mid=0;
    int c=0;
    if(lo<hi)
    {
        mid=(lo+hi)/2;
        if(p[mid]==t) c=1;
        else if(t>p[mid]) 
            bins(p,mid+1,hi,t);
        else if(t<p[mid]) 
            bins(p,0,mid,t);
    }
     return c;
}

int main()
{
    clrscr();
    int target;
    int k;
    int count=0;
    cout<<"Enter the number of elements:";
    cin>>k;
    int* numbers=new int(k);
    cout<<"Enter the target element"<<endl;
    cin>>target;
    cout<<"Enter the elements:"<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
       cin>>numbers[i];
    int* nu=new int(k);
    memset(nu,0,sizeof(int));
    /*for(i=0;i<k;i++){
    cout<<numbers[i]<<endl;
    }*/
    for(i=0;i<k;i++)
    {
        int bool=bins(nu,0,k,numbers[i]);
        //printf("%d\n",bool);
        if(bool)
        {
             count++;
        }
        else
        {
            int tg=target-numbers[i];
            cout<<"targetval:"<<tg<<endl;
            nu[i]=tg;
        }
        //bool?count++:(nu[i]=target-numbers[i]);
    }
    cout<<"Count is:"<<count<<endl;
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

this is the code i have written for TwoSum problem in leetcode,instead of using HashMap whose time complexity is O(n) i used binary search whose complexity is O(logn)
The problem i'm facing is the input i give to the array numbers[i] takes only 3 values and from then it stores junk values even after assigining proper inputs from console
this program has been compiled  succesfully on Turbocompiler on system

Comment: Where did you get your complexities from? Hash table lookup is constant on average (linear in the worst case) and binary search is logarithmic.

Answer (score 1):

```
int* numbers=new int[k];////allocates an array of k adjacent integers. (undefined values)
```

You are allocating for an array. Check the notations.

Also you are using a keyword as a variable.(`bool`).

What have you done?

```
int *numbers=new int(k);////allocates an integer, set to k. (same syntax as constructors)
```

Answer (score 0):

Leetcode doesn't give exact code. It will have syntax errors or compilation erros. You have to fix them to make it work. In this case, following are the issues,

```
int* numbers=new int[k]; //not int* numbers=new int(k);
```

Another thing is that `bool` is a keyword, that is used to give `true` or `false` for variables. You have to use another variable.